# On the behaviour of a "mean-value" function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, and define $g_f:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$g_f(x) = \inf\left\{\delta \in (0,x) : f'(\delta) = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right\}$$

We may note that $g_f$ need not be continuous. For instance, if $f(x)=0$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = (x-1)^2$ for $x>1$. We might also note that $g_f$ need not be monotone (for instance, if $f(x)=\sin x$).

However, I'm going to conjecture that the discontinuity set of $g_f$ is not too ugly. Specifically I'd venture to guess that in the worst case, it's countably infinite (and if not that, perhaps measure zero). I'm looking for results (or counterexamples) in this direction.

Comment: I would try to check if $g_f$ is semicontinuous (upper or lower)